# Approximation of real number to the power of irrational

Tags: approximation, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

Say I have two numbers, $c\in\Bbb R^+\,,q\in\Bbb{R\setminus Q}$.

Is there a way to approximate the value of $c^q$?

This question bugging me because of how simple it sound in compare to how complicated it is. First I want to understand what a power of irrational number is, when talking about $\Bbb R^+$(I use this domain for sake of simplicity) we have very well defined actions for power a rational number, we can even use some theorems to get $c^{a/b}=\sqrt[b]{c^a}$, but when I am dealing with irrational number I can not do this.

I know that we have some definition for this because the solution of the equation $2^x=3$ is irrational.

So what exactly does it mean to take something to a irrational power and is there a way to approximate a numeric value for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I answer your question, let me ask another question: how do you compute $\pi\times e$? How do you multiply irrational numbers? If multiplication is understood as repeated addition, how can you add a thing $\pi$ times?

I submit that real exponents are no different than real multipliers.

By definition, real numbers are numbers that can be approximated by rationals. For example, $\sqrt{2}$ is the real number defined by successively better approximating rationals $1,1.4,1.41,1.414,\cdots.$ Then the multiplication $\sqrt{2}\times 2$ is defined as the real number approximated by $1\times 2,1.4\times 2,1.41\times 2,1.414\times 2,\cdots,=2,2.8,2.82,2.828,\cdots.$ Hence we conclude that $\sqrt{2}\times 2\approx 2.828,$ by doing the computation on the approximating rationals.

Similarly powers with real exponents are defined as numbers approximated by corresponding powers with rational exponents.

For example, to compute $2^{\sqrt{2}}$, we just raise $2$ to the power of each approximating rational. So our sequence approximating $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is $2^1,2^{1.4},2^{1.41},2^{1.414},\cdots = 2,2.64,2.657,2.6647,\cdots.$ So we say that $2^{\sqrt{2}}\approx 2.6647.$

For another example, I'll use the proposed example from your question. Let $x$ be the real number represented by the sequence of rationals $1, 1.5, 1.58, 1.584, 1.5849,\dotsc$ seems to converge to a real number. No repeating decimal places, so it’s an irrational number.

Let’s exponentiate it. Then $2^x$ is the sequence $2^1, 2^{1.5}, 2^{1.58}, 2^{1.584}, 2^{1.5849},\dotsc$ and we get $2, 2.83, 2.99, 2.998, 3.00,\dotsc$

The latter sequence approaches the real number $3$, hence the former sequence $x$ is the real solution to the equation $2^x=3.$ Or in short, $x=\log_23.$

And that's what it means to exponentiate a real. Just as every real may be represented by approximating rationals, the exponential of a real is approximated by the exponentiation of its approximating rationals.

These approximating rationals can either be understood as [Cauchy sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence), [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut), or plain old strings of [decimal expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_representation).

Comment: I gather you'd define rational powers by $c^{p/q}=\sqrt[q]{c^p}$. Do you know an easy/clean way to show that if $c>0$ and $r_n$ is a Cauchy sequence of rationals then $c^{r_n}$ converges, starting with that definition?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich at the moment it is not obvious to me, no. The more I think about how I would prove it, the more it sounds like re-inventing calculus of the exponentials. However it seems pretty clear that the exponential of a Dedekind cut is again a Dedekind cut.

Comment: Right. Seems to me that what you said is maybe the simplest and most intuitive way to answer the question here, but if one wants to actually develop the theory rigorously what I said works out a lot nicer.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Another route is to declare the exponential to be the unique function satisfying $y'=y, y(0)=1$, which is guaranteed to exist for all arguments, including irrational. I like this option because it seems like a natural (infinitesimal) extension of the equation $a^{x+y}=a^xa^y,$ which in my opinion should be regarded as the "true" definition of exponentiation. Of course, when you unpack the concepts, it's the same idea as my rational approximation, and your Taylor series. Just dressed up in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to define what it means to take a real power of a real number is to define $$\exp(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!},$$to define the logarithm of a positive number in any of various ways, and then define $$c^p=\exp(p\log(c))\quad(c>0, p\in\mathbb R).$$

Of course we can approximate this. One way to define $\log(c)$ is $\int_1^c\frac{dt}t$; you can use standard methods for approximating integrals. Then you can approximate $\exp(p\log(c))$ by taking finitely many terms of that power series.